# How to convert value of aspx combobox selected item to int?

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox

I know it is very basic but I failed.

```
public static int devId;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

It is working ! I set value static

```
protected void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    devId = 325283298;  
}
```

It is not working !

```
protected void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    devId = int.Parse(cmbDealer.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
}

<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cmbDealer" runat="server" TextField="FirmName" 

         ValueField="DeviceID" EnableSynchronization="False"  Width="130" 

         EnableIncrementalFiltering="True"   DataSourceID="lnqDealer1" 

          Theme="Youthful">

</dx:ASPxComboBox>
```

Comment: Have you tried checking what the value is of the selected Item? You may have a problem with your binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys !

Solved by

```
devId=Convert.ToInt32(cmbDealer.SelectedItem.Value.ToString())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code.
if i am not wrong then you want to get the selected value of dropdownn.
so you can use below code.

**code**

```
devId=Convert.ToInt32(cmbDealer.SelectedValue);
```

with this code you will get the selected value of dropdown.
i hope it will helpful.

Comment: There is no SelectedValue in cmdDealer.But Solved by devId=Convert.ToInt32(cmbDealer.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `SelectedIndex` property before converting the value.

```
if(cmbDealer.SelectedIndex>-1)
devId = Convert.ToInt32(cmbDealer.SelectedItem.ToString());
```